# convert text file to html ouput so that data can be printed in table format

Tags: html, linux, shell

I have a text file which has 3 values separated by :

```
25-08-2019_19.00.00 : Port port1 of URL http://ip1:port1/ is  NOT OPEN :  Zoom1
25-08-2019_19.00.00 : Port port2 of URL http://ip2:port2/ is  NOT OPEN :  MP
```

and so on.
I want to print the output to a html type tabular format file, which has 3 headings, date, output and system and corresponding data in 3 columns.

I tried below code, but it is not putting data to table format.

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
   echo "USAGE: $(basename $0) file1 file2 file3 ..."
   exit 1
fi

for file in $* ; do
   html=$(echo $file | sed 's/\.txt$/\.html/i')

   echo "<html>" >> $html
   echo "<style type="text/css">
        table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
        </style>" >> $html
   echo "   <body>" >> $html
   echo '<table>' >> $htm
   echo '<th>HEADING1</th>' >> $html
   echo '<th>HEADING2</th>' >> $html
   echo '<th>HEADING3</th>' >> $html

   while IFS=':' read -ra line ; do
    echo "<tr>" >> $html
    for i in "${line[@]}"; do
       echo "<td>$i</td>" >> $html
     # echo "<td>$i</td>" >> $html
      done
     echo "</tr>" >> $html
   done < $file
    echo '</table>'
    echo "   </body>" >> $html
    echo "</html>" >> $html
done
```

Comment: I don't have a bash interpreter here, but I'm pretty sure you need to escape the quotes inside quotes. And you're not echoing everything to $html. Anyway, you need to tell us what goes wrong exactly. Do you get errors, etc.

Comment: Putting most of the code into ``(…) >$html`` would make it easier to read, and would have made at least one bug (the missing ``>>$html`` on the ``</table>`` line) impossible to have happened.  On the other hand, writing the command to process only one file (or standard input) and to write the results to standard output would make it a lot simpler and more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, please consider `awk`:

```
awk -F' : ' '
  BEGIN{
    print "<html><style type=\"text/css\">table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;}</style><body><table><th>HEADING1</th><th>HEADING2</th><th>HEADING3</th>"
  } 
  {
     print "<tr>"
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
       print "<td>" $i "</td>"
     print "</tr>"
  }
  END{
    print "</table></body></html>"
  }
' input_file > output.html
```

The `BEGIN` and `END` statement fills the static html tags.

The middle statement fills one line of the array according to each input file line by adding `<tr>` for each line and `<td>` for each field.